# <div> will not move down a line

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a border and some content and I am trying to put some text to act as a header, but the div will not move down a line to make room for the text. Here is my code.

```
            <span style="width: 100%; position:absolute">Mountain Bikes</span>
            <?php                   
                for($i = 0; $i < count($model); $i++)
                {          
                  if($type[$i] == "Mountain")
                    {
                    echo("<div id=\"bikes\">");
                    echo(" <img src=" . $image[$i] . " style=\"float: left; margin-left: 200px; margin-top: 5px; width: 300px; height: 190px; position: absolute\" alt=\"No Picutre sorry\">");
                    echo("Brand: " . $brand[$i]);
                    echo("  <br> Model: " . $model[$i]);
                    echo(" <br>Color: " . $color[$i]);
                    echo("<br>Gender: " . $gender[$i]);
                    echo(" <br> Price: " . $price[$i]);
                    echo("<br> Mountain Bike" .  "</div><br><br>");
                }
               }
               ?>

                <span style="width: 100%; position:absolute; font-size: 50px;">Road Bikes</span>

            <?php
                for($i = 0; $i < count($model); $i++)
                {          
                  if($type[$i] == "Road")
                    {
                    echo("<div id=\"bikes\">");
                    echo(" <img src=" . $image[$i] . " style=\"float: left; margin-left: 200px; margin-top: 5px; width: 300px; height: 190px; position: absolute\" alt=\"No Picutre sorry\">");
                    echo("Brand: " . $brand[$i]);
                    echo("  <br> Model: " . $model[$i]);
                    echo(" <br>Color: " . $color[$i]);
                    echo("<br>Gender: " . $gender[$i]);
                    echo(" <br> Price: " . $price[$i]);
                    echo("<br> Road Bike" .  "</div><br><br>");
                }
               }

               ?>
```

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxZudoaQ00qRSmJoZ1lMR2VuZG8/view?usp=sharing]

Sorry, the mountain bike text is small right now, but I want that on top of the first box, and the road bike title to move down under all the mountain bike boxes.

Comment: Why bother with all those loops? `$i = array_search('Mountain', $type)`

Comment: You are using absolute positioning on the headings which is removing them from the flow of the page.

Comment: You should try not to mix style and html like that. I would start by removing all "style" attributes from the code and moving the styling to a CSS file or at least block. On another topic, "position: absolute" does remove an element from the flow, so it won't move other elements when it shows. I am guessing those spans are what you're calling "headers", you might consider making them header tags (h1, h2, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of the absolute positioning, then add 'clear:both;' as a CSS rule to anything you want to start a new line with.

i.e.:

```
<span>Mountain Bikes</span>
<div>Image</div>
<span>Title #2</span>
<div>Image</div>

div, span{
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to give me more to work with. A jsfiddle or codepen would be great. 

Here's an example of what I'm suggesting:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azZaKe

Notice how the second div wraps to the next line. Remember that, in order for 'clear:both' to work (in fact, for it to matter at all), the element being cleared has to have a float rule applied.

Comment: Thanks, after checking your code snippet, my title div was not floated left. works perfect now!!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to give you some cleaner version of the code.

```
        <style>
          .bikes { 
             position: relative;
             min-width: 300px;
             min-height: 190px;
          }
          .bikes img {
             position: absolute;
             width: 300px;
             height: 190px;
           }
        </style>
        <?php
            function bike_toString($i) {
                $ret = "<div class=\"bikes\">";
                $ret.= "<img src=" . $image[$i] . " alt=\"No Picture, sorry\">";
                $ret.= "<p>Brand: " . $brand[$i]."</p>";
                $ret.= "<p> Model: " . $model[$i]."</p>";
                $ret.= "<p>Color: " . $color[$i]."</p>";
                $ret.= "<p>Gender: " . $gender[$i]."</p>";
                $ret.= "<p> Price: " . $price[$i]."</p>";
                $ret.= "<p>";
                switch($type) {
                   case 'Mountain': $ret.= "Mountain bike"; break;
                   case 'Road': $ret.= "Road Bike"; break;
                   default: "";
                $ret.= " </p></div>";
                return $ret;
            }
            for($i = 0; $i < count($model); $i++)
            {          
              switch($type[$i]) }
               case "Mountain": $mountains.= bike_toString($i); break;
               case "Road": $roads.= bike_toString($i); break;
               default: break;
            }
           }
           ?>
           <h2>Mountain Bikes</h2>
              <?php echo $mountains; ?>
            <h2>Road Bikes</h2>
              <?php echo $roads; ?>
```

It isn't perfect, but if I didn't make any typos it should work and be easier to maintain. If you have the power, however, I would suggest it'd be simpler to save your data in a more traversable way, an array of objects for example.